# Can autoPlay SwipperJS disabled and enabled programmatically?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

So I have multiple arrays with different lengths. I want to show it in swiper. is it possible to enable the autoplay in Swipper if the number of items in the array is more than 5 and disable it if it is less than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You have 2 options.

First option is to render the Swipper component conditionally like this:

```js
if(myArray.length > 5) {
  return (
   <Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      autoplay={{
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      }}
   >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      ...
   </Swiper>
  );
} else {
  return (
   <Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
   >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      ...
   </Swiper>
  );
}
```

And the second way you can do this is to enable it by default and then use the [stop](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-autoplay-stop) method to stop it like this (You can see the examples [here](https://swiperjs.com/react)):

```js
const swiperRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  if(swiperRef.current && myArray.length < 5) {
    swiperRef.current.swiper.autoplay.stop();
  }
}, [myArray]);

return (
 <Swiper
    ref={swiperRef}
    spaceBetween={50}
    slidesPerView={3}
    autoplay={{
      delay: 2500,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    }}
 >
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
    ...
 </Swiper>
);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, very helpful.
actually, I know there is a `swiper.autoplay.stop()` method but I don't know how to implement it. every time I write it there is `ReferenceError: swiper is not defined.`
and if I write `var swipper = new Swipper` there will be `TypeError: swiper_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Swiper is not a constructor`.

Comment: I updated my answer. It solves your issue.